# recursion in main method

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Anybody know why the answer to this is 12 and not 10?

```
public static int recurse (int x) {
if (x < 1)
return x;
else
return (x + recurse (x-2));
}
public static void main(String [] args) {
System.out.println (recurse(6));
}
```

Comment: Because 6+4+2+0 is 12 and not 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) to understand why it evaluates to 12. You can start by explaining to your duck, "Because 6 is not less than 1, recurse( 6 ) is the same as 6 + recurse( 6 - 2 )".